# Посчитать количество сообщений ВК

Tags: vkontakte-api, api, вконтакте

Как можно посчитать количество сообщений ВК за X времени (к примеру сообщения за неделю)? Метод `messages.getHistory` не подходит, ведь они считают за всё время.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Записывай сообщения в базу данных. Сам использую MySQL.

```
SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE time > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL '1 MINUTES') AND `chat_id` = 1
```

Также с сообщениями храни дату в виде: 2021-06-01 00:00:00 (datetime)